# What is the cheapest way to connect a 12V input into a PIC?

Tags: resistors, pic, input, button

I have a pushbutton which delivers 12V when is pushed. I want to connect it to a PIC12F1572 input pin. What is the proper way to do it?

My idea was to use voltage divider  to reduce voltage under 5V using two resistors and another resistor, maybe 100k in series to limit the current.

Another idea was to use an optocoupler,  but is a little bit expensive and space on the PCB is so limited.

Comment: You do not have to limit the current since the PICs have Mosfet inputs (high impedance). Just use a two resistor divider.

Comment: Why use 3 resistors, as 2 resistors will already divide the voltage and limit current?

Comment: Do you need ESD protection?

Comment: `delivers 12V` ... AC or DC? ... what supplies the voltage?

Answer (score 3):

> Another idea was to use optocoupler

It's required when the two systems are isolated (i.e. don't have the same ground).

---

Voltage divider is the simplest solution but requires a few things to consider.

**1) LOGIC LEVELS:** From the I/O ports electrical characteristics, for logic input, I can see that

- logic-low can be as high as 1V i.e. up to 1V is considered as LOW
- logic-high can be as low as 4V i.e. at least 4V is considered as HIGH

[image: I/O Ports Electrical Characteristics]

**2) MAXIMUM VOLTAGES:** From the absolute maximum ratings I can see that the voltage that a GPIO pin sees shouldn't exceed VDD+0.3V (which appears to be 5.3V for your application) **in any case**, so you should consider the maximum available VDD in your circuit (e.g. what if VDD can be, say, 5.05V).

The maximum voltage coming from the button should also be considered. If it's, say, noisy or if it has ripple then the output voltage of the divider will change. In this case the output shouldn't exceed the absolute maximum voltage.

So, from **1**, your divider should be designed such that "the worst case output" *(e.g. when the button output is at its expected minimum such as 11V)* should be at least 4V. And from **2**, the output of the divider should never exceed VDD+0.3V.

**3) GPIO INPUT CURRENT:** This is the current that leaks into/out of the pin. It's defined as less than 1 uA so can be assumed as 1 uA max. The total current of the divider (12V / total resistance) should be high enough so that the 1 uA leakage can be neglected i.e. it doesn't affect the behaviour of the divider therefore change the output voltage.

**4) DEBOUNCE REJECTION:** Although this can be done in the software it's still good to implement a hardware de-bounce filter. It's a simple RC so a small capacitor across the output of the divider works fine. Try not to put a large cap as it'll slow down the output rise.

So, here's the result:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZlgKw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The input is clamped with a 5V1 Zener in case the button output is higher than 12V. The total current of the divider (flows through R1) is selected high enough so the input pin leakage current doesn't change the behaviour. 22k keeps the input grounded in case the button is removed. 100n clears up de-bounce, can be increased if needed.

The circuit above works for logic high voltages down to 9V, and logic low voltages up to 1V.

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If the grounds are shared and the 12 V source isn't noisy (motors and whatever), you can do something as simple as a voltage divider.  If your grounds aren't shared or your 12 V isn't suitable then use an optocoupler (see other answer).

51K and 36K chosen from E24 range to be close to 7:5 ratio.  If the 12V isn't accurate you might prefer say 30K and 18K => 4.5V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSGj3I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: As a comment to your question says, you don't need a 3rd current limiting resistor and the two resistors will limit the current themselves if you are still worried. You should also read Rohat's answer about debouncing the switch. 100nF across R2 should do it.

Answer (score 2):

If the button is connected to a vehicle electrical system, the input signal can have all kinds of nastiness on it. One circuit I have used in the past is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr2WXt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 and C1 form a low-pass filter that eliminates RFI and provides a certain amount of debouncing.

D1 and the B-E junction of Q1 are back-to-back diodes that limit the swing of the base node to ±0.7 V. Even if the input hits ±200 V, R1 limits the current to ±2 mA.

Whenever the input is greater than a volt or two, Q1 conducts and pulls the MCU pin low.

Comment: Thank you for all explication, that`s help me a lot to understand the idea behind, not just copy your circuit. Is somehow inverted driver, right? It will reduce lifetime of MCU if all time is applied voltage on input?

Comment: If the MCU is powered by a battery, then yes, the continuous current through R2 (about 1 mA) would drain it sooner. R2 could be much larger if this is a problem.

Comment: Did you have circuit with non-inverting output? I'm afraid about drain, because will be connected to car battery. Or just make R2 to 10k should be ok?

Comment: Sure, you could make R2 as high as 100k with no problems. But I don't understand the application. Are you saying that the pushbutton is pushed for extended times when the engine is off? If so, your original idea of the resistive divider has the same problem with long-term current draw. Perhaps you should edit your question to explain exactly what your application is and what your power constraints are.

Comment: Yes, my solution with voltage divider had same problem, but I was thinking about add another resistor, in series 100k, to limit current.

Comment: Hello, and sorry for re-open this subject. Will work this circuit if the input signal is a PWM?

Comment: Only if you remove C1, or at least reduce its value so that the cutoff frequency of the R1-C1 low-pass filter is significantly higher than the PWM frequency.